# How to mock third party components that are not constructor dependency?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

```
export class ComponentDetailsComponent implements OnInit {   
    @ViewChild('treeGridReference') treeGrid: jqxTreeGridComponent;
....more code....
  this.treeGrid.clearSelection();// how do I mock this?
}
```

Had it been a constructor dependency I could have just created a stub for `jqxTreeGridComponent` with empty `clearSelection` method, something similar to :

```
class jqxTreeGridComponentStub{
  clearSelection(){}
  }
}
{ provide: jqxTreeGridComponent, useClass: jqxTreeGridComponentStub },
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240163/mocking-child-components-angular-2

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a mock component in your declarations array in configure Testing module,

```
@Component({selector: 'jqxTreeGridComponent-selector', template: ''})
class jqxTreeGridComponent{
   clearSelection(){}
}

describe('', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [ ComponentDetailsComponent , jqxTreeGridComponent],
            }).compileComponents();
        }));
    })
}
```

To read more about stub components, read [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#stubbing-unneeded-components) in the documentation.

Comment: That doesn't ensure the provided component is a variable inside the parent component (although with the testbed it probably will). Also, this prevents the mocking, meaning you provide the actual component, which is a bad practice in unit testing

Comment: You are not just testing a class, but a Component and it includes your template as well, View child will create the variable with the stub component you provided.

It's how you add Shallow components while testing. There are 2 ways to do it, and it is mentioned in the documentation. https://angular.io/guide/testing#stubbing-unneeded-components

Don't just down vote, if it's an alternative.

Comment: If you look only at the code provided, you *assume* he's testing the template. Nothing states that the test bed is used. And often, the template is tested through e2e testing and not through unit testing. Your solution assumes too many things and is suited for only specific scenarios. I don't say you're wrong, don't mistake my words ! I'm saying your answer is too specific for the poor quantity of code provided.

Comment: Well, he added the unit test tag to the question. And writing unit tests without TestBed, good luck with that. Also in the documentation, it's mentioned if you are interacting with the child component, this method is a good option.

**The stub component approach has another advantage. While the stubs in this example were empty, you could give them stripped-down templates and classes if your tests need to interact with them in some way.**

Comment: All of my unit testing is done without the test bed ... And it's way faster. And again, I don't say you're wrong, I say you're assuming too much. Could you care to read a message when I take time to write it ?

Comment: Cool, I assumed he is using TestBed, which most of angular developers are. Well, it is still an alternative in that case.

Comment: I am using TestBed but I am not performing e2e tests I am keeping template out of it. I am only testing component