# Testing UpgradeComponent throws NullInjectorError: No provider for $injector! error

Tags: angular, angular-test, angular-upgrade

I have a angularjs component that I am upgrading:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Injector, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

@Directive({
  selector: 'up'
})
export class UpDirective extends UpgradeComponent {
  constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, injector: Injector) {
    super('old', elementRef, injector);
  }
}
```

This component works just fine when I run the application.

However when I try and test the Angular 8 component that uses that directive I get the following error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[$injector]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[$injector]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for $injector!
```

I assume that is coming from the injector that is used in the UpgradeComponent.  However I am not sure how to provide that to my spec.ts.

Angular does a good job documenting how to make this work in an application, but nothing on how to test: https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeComponent

Also looked here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24369, however still not clear how to test.

Comment: Very much annoyed with the same issue now. For some reason, component mocking doesn't work for me. I will leave the link here for others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41240163/mocking-child-components-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/95fbb7d675d43e6d9954a3f8efb051fcf2f1f58a/packages/upgrade/test/static/integration/upgrade_component_spec.ts#L26-L64) of how you can setup tests for components using it. Hard to be more helpful without a stackblitz, but when I had to test something similar this worked for me.

When I did it I just took that stuff outside of the "it" so it could be used as a setup. Pretty sure I did most of that setup in the beforeEach. Just had the variables I needed declared in the describe but initialized in the beforeEach so they could be used in the tests.

Hard to be more helpful without a stackblitz.